# How to Establish a connection to ALM using REST API

Tags: rest, qtp, alm

I have a Couple of Questions which need to be clarified below 
1)What is Meant by a REST client 
2)What is the difference between OTA API vs REST API in ALM during connectivity. 
I have already established a connection with OTA. Can anyone provide a sample code to establish a connection with ALM using REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) REST client - it depends what you mean: or HPE ALM Web Client (that works using REST architecture) or ALM REST Api

HPE ALM Web Client was announced in ALM 12.01 and was decommissioned in ALM 12.50
It allowed to work with requirements and defects modules

ALM REST Api - RESTful API that allow create, read, update, and delete data on the ALM

2) Using OTA you need to initialize connection to server using:

```
set tdc = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
tdc.InitConnectionEx ServerName
```

When using REST API yo need to:
POST on {ServerNasme}/qcbin/api/authentication/sign-in with header:
  Authorization: Basic {Login:Password encoded with Base64}
thats return you next cookies: 
   ALM_USER
   LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY
   QCSession
   XSRF-TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

Answer to all you questions is in API documentation. Go to this link : http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/Latest/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#General/Overview.html%3FTocPath%3D_____1

For creating a connection have a look at "Authenticate Login Logout Example" Here:

http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/Latest/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#CodeSamples/AuthenticateLoginLogoutExample.htm%3FTocPath%3DExample%2520Application%7C_____2

Comment: :Thanks for providing the info... I will go through this and ask you if there is any doubt